# Erlang with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, erlang

Is there a way to use visual studio 2015 as my Erlang Programming ide. Found a plugin for intellij idea. Can anyone please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is one plugin for [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pgourlain.erlang)

Comment: upps ... Thanks for the reply. Then which one you suggest as the best IDE.?